# Python C API function arguments

Tags: python, python-c-api

How can I define a function, or a contructor for a class with specified arguments using the C API?

By default function takes `PyObject*` args, and later in the code the linter won’t show real arguments.

If it’s not possible, is there a way to bypass it? I came up with two possible options:

1. Wrap every function in python code

   ```py
   def f(x: int, y: int) -> int:
       return _c_module(x, y)
   ```
2. Maybe `.pyi` files could somehow do the trick(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use `.pyi` files and distribute them with your package (look at the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files)), i.e. if you have a module `my_mod` with class `Baz` with member `foo` and method `bar`, then you would want to have `my_mod.pyi` like this:

```py
class Baz:
    foo: float

    def bar(self, param_a: str, default_one: int = ...) -> str:
        pass
```

And then most linters, type checkers, etc. would catch this up and work with it.

Additionally: [about stubs from mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html).

Comment: @kebabdubai if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.